# SSH external starting and external ending ports

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding, netgear-router

I'm currently trying to port forward my SSH server (home laptop). The problem is that the router admin page gives me two options: an external starting port and an external ending port. I know that all the guides recommend using port 22, but how can I use port 22 if there's **2 ports**.

Answer (score 0):

The admin page allows you to define a range of ports. If all you need is a range of 1 port, then just enter '22' in both start & end fields.